# Upload excel spreadsheet as an Azure DevOps source file in C# automation project

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-automation

I have a C# Excel automation project that runs in a release pipeline and resides in the same repo as my production code, though in a different solution file. I would like to have the automation project use canned Excel workbooks as a starting point for the automation instead of creating new workbooks and dynamically populating cells with user defined function calls.

The automation project is an NUnit test project that compiles into a DLL and I want to have a separate directory of workbooks that is not compiled into the automation DLL.

My question is on the best way to do this. Should I just include a folder of Excel workbooks in my automation project.

How do I get these files into the build pipeline so that the release pipeline has access to them along with the MSI install file and the automation DLL?  This assumes that I should implement this as part of the build pipeline instead of downloading the files as part of the release pipeline process triggered by the build pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

> The automation project is an NUnit test project that compiles into a
>   DLL and want to have a separate directory of workbooks that is not
>   compiled into the automation DLL.

If I am not misunderstand this requirement, you want this workbook can exist with Dlls, but don't want it be compiled.

In Visual studio, there has a option can achieve the similar feature.

**Right click** the excel file -> **Properties**, and choose the corresponding action about `Copy to Output Directory`:

[image]

Corresponding to this operation, the .csproj file will be added some scripts:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="MyFile.xlsx">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Using [`<CopyToOutputDirectory>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2019) to determines whether this file would be **copied** to the output directory where the Dlls located. In your requirement, here you should specify the workbook.

---

Same in Azure Devops Service, if you add the above script into `.csproj` by specifying the corresponding workbook. Then this workbook will be generated into the `output` folder together with the `dlls`. The most important things is that this workbook will not be compiled, because it just be **copied** into the output.

Just configure the build pipeline as normal, along with using `Publish Build artifacts` task to **pack** these output. Then the release pipeline would get and access it.